# How to block users on Firebase in a social media app? for iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoaJR.png)I'm about 90% with my app, and was ready to release it so it can be released to get tested.

I was rejected by apple, because i didn't have a very important feature: -  A mechanism for users to block abusive users.

I already have a function in which I follow other users, but I'm stuck on how do I block access, so that when one users blocks the other, they don't see anything related to the one who just blocked him. They can't see their profile in search, in new messages, and their posts.

i don't know where to begin. If you've worked on a user-content generated app. I don't even know where to begin. I've been stuck on this for 3 weeks and now I'm desperate.

//how would I implement something like this?

my security rules are basic.

```
{
  "rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
```

}
}

the way i display information, as of right now, is that users have to log in with just an email and username and password using and that creates' and user that allows them to log in, into the app and see everything related to the app.

my nodes as well

```
Messages
```

comments
flagged-posts
following
likes
posts
user-messages
users

Comment: Do you mind posting your security rules? Or, how you facilitate the displaying of information for users? Something that will allow us to get a better idea of how your system works to help you integrate a blocking feature.

Comment: @BryanMassoth apologies, just added more details, sorry. let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of solutions to this problem. One way is to have a separate node in the database for blocked users. Under each user, you can list the `uid` of the blocked user with a value of "true". Doesn't really matter what the value is--this just makes it easier to search for who is blocked. So, for example, say this is your database structure:

```
users:
    uid1:
       my data: {
           // some stuff here
       }
    uid2:
       my data: {
           // some stuff here
       }
blocked:
     uid1:
         uid8: true,
         uid3: true
     uid2:
         uid1: true
```

In the above example, `uid1` has blocked `uid8` and `uid3`, and so on.
Then you can align your rules to verify that the user can read if they are authenticated and their `uid` isn't found on that user's blocked list.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // only messages from the last ten minutes can be read
        ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blocked/'+$user_id+'/'+auth.uid+'/true').exists()",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) on security rules for some examples of security rules.

Comment: I think I'm very close to the solution. I'm not sure, why when I implement the security rules, I'm constantly getting "firebase access denied on all users. My nodes are the same as in this example.

Comment: 4.12.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /posts/93WZmGheisepemNsMPKj0RJlYq53 failed: permission_denied

Comment: and the thing is it's happening for all users, even the one that's doing the blocking..

Comment: Messages
blocked
93WZmGheisepemNsMPKj0RJlYq53
wFsUB1B4d9SvSBKzI0PzzYSXGic2: 
true
comments
flagged-posts
following
likes
posts
user-messages
users

Comment: I included a screenshot of my database structure. it's right at the beginning, with my ranking it doesn't let me upload images yet.

Comment: @EdisonEspinosa why didn’t you pick this answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: @EdisonEspinosa what solution did you come up with?

Comment: I didn't come up with anything, everything I tried didn't work.. I found a way to just hack it, so I can get my app approved by apple.

Comment: I still do have to find a way, so i'll try later for sure. As the app grows and an user needs to block an user..

Comment: Interested to know what hack did you use? My app has some social elements eg; messaging, discover users etc.. so I need to prepare to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I asume somewhere in your DB you have a User Model correct? simply add another field called isBlocked or whatever and according to that value you'd validate if certain users can see that user or not

Comment: how would I validate it? I've tried the solution above, but instead every user is getting their access denied overall

Comment: It''s because security rules apply to everything in the DB, you want these rules to each individual user

Comment: what would be the proper DB rules?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it works fine for me. **It isn't like instagram where the blocked user completely disappears from your feed** but it will definitely keep Apple at bay because one user can block another user and once that happens **neither** can send a message to one another.

It also gives you the option to show a "block" or "unblock" when the action sheet is presented so that way the current user knows wether they did or didn't block the other user.

First thing is I'm assuming this is inside some sort of chat view controller that has a send message button and inside that chat vc there is the sender's id (current user) and the receiver's id (other user).

To block someone you create a `blocked` ref in Firebase, create a node for the user who wants to block the other user and then finally add the blocked user as a key/value pair under that node. The `other user's id` is the `key` and the value can be true.

For eg. *dog123* wants to block *cat456*. When the dog decides to block the cat the ref to block at would be would be:

```
let dogId = dog123 // current user
let catId = cat456 // other user

func actionSheetBlockedAction() {

    let dictValues = [String: Any]()
    dictValues.updateValue(true, forKey: catId)

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(dogId)
    ref.updateChildValues(dictValues)
}
```

This would result in the database looking like:

```
root
  |
  @---blocked
         |
         |
         @----dog123
                |
                |----cat456: true  // cat123 is blocked from sending messages to dog123
```

Inside the same chat vc you need to add some properties and in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear you need to add 2 separate observers to listen to the blocked ref for both users.

You have to run a check on both user's because yeah dog123 might have blocked cat456 but in return cat456 might also have blocked dog123. Later on if the dog decides to unblock the cat but the cat still has the dog blocked then messages will still get through from the dog to the cat.

To prevent that you add the observers and they'll toggle on some properties that you check when the send button is pressed. If either of the properties are true that means somebody blocked somebody else and no messages should get sent. The properties will let you know who blocked who.

You can also use those properties to show the "block" or "unblock" button when the action sheet appears.

```
var currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var otherUserId = "whatever" // you should already have this
var isCurrentUserBlocked = false
var isOtherUserBlocked = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    checkBlockedRefsForBothUsers() // this is where the isCurrentUserBlocked & isOtherUserBlocked properties get changed
}


@IBAction func sendMessageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if isOtherUserBlocked {
        // alert the current user that they blocked the other user
        return
    }

    if isCurrentUserBlocked {
        // alert the current user that the other user blocked them
        return
    }

    // if neither are true then let the current user send their message to the other user
}


func checkBlockedRefsForBothUsers() {

    let currentUsersBlockedRef = Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(currentUserId!)
    currentUsersBlockedRef?.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // if the current user ISN'T under the blocked ref then the other user ISN'T blocked
        if !snapshot.exists() {
            self.isOtherUserBlocked = false
            return
        }

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

            // if the other user's uid IS under the current user's blocked ref then the other user IS blocked from them
            if snap.key == self.otherUsersId {
                self.isOtherUserBlocked = true
                break
            }

             // if the other user's uid ISN'T under the current user's blocked ref then the other user ISN'T blocked
            self.isOtherUserBlocked = false
        }
    })

    let otherUsersBlockedRef = Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(otherUserId)
    otherUsersBlockedRef?.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // if the other user's uid ISN'T under the blocked ref then the current user ISN'T blocked
        if !snapshot.exists() {
            self.isCurrentUserBlocked = false
            return
        }

        for child in snapshot.children {

            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

            // if the current user's uid IS under the other user's blocked ref then the current user IS blocked from them
            if snap.key == self.currentUserId {
                self.isCurrentUserBlocked = true
                break
            }

             // if the current user's uid ISN'T under the other user's blocked ref then the current user ISN'T blocked
            self.isCurrentUserBlocked = false
        }
    })
}
```

And to show a "block" or "unblock" button when the action sheet is presented use those same 2 properties:

```
@IBAction func presentActionSheet(sender: UIButton) {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let blockAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Block", style: .default) { (action) in
         // run code to block the otherUserId
         self.actionSheetBlockedAction()
    }

    let unblockAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Unblock", style: .default) { (action) in
        // run code to unblock the otherUserId
    }

    if isOtherUserBlocked {
        actionSheet.addAction(unblockAction) // if the current user blocked the other user then show the "unblock" action
    } else {
        actionSheet.addAction(blockAction)  // if the current user didn't block the other user then show the "block" action
    }

    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally you might think to yourself that when the dog blocked the cat it would make sense to just update the refs for both of them. The problem with that is when the cat's action sheet is presented, using the logic above it will appear that the cat blocked the dog and the cat's action sheet will show "unblock".